# VMware workstation pro 12.1 server/shared - VM drag and drop support

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-server

I have a remote shared Windows 7 VM (Windows 10 host, VMware workstation pro 12.1) that I have connected to with VMware workstation pro 12.0 from a Windows 7 machine.

How do I make drag and drop support work for this instance? When I run the VM locally I can drag and drop into it without issue. I have tried from another Windows 10 machine with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't.

From [the documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-2410A786-D013-48A9-8D57-4C6A7263F652.html):

> You interact with remote virtual machines in the same way that you interact with local virtual machines, but some features and devices are not supported. Features that you cannot use with remote virtual machines include Unity mode, shared folders, AutoProtect snapshots, drag-and-drop, and copy and paste.

Comment: Your support link doesn't say it can't be done.  I have enabled drag and drop support using a VMware VM and I used Workstation at the time.

Comment: @Ramhound "Features that you cannot use with remote virtual machines..." does say that it cannot be done. (That said, I believe that are some configuration options that supposedly allow copy/paste to work with remote VMs, but 1. I have never been able to get them to work; 2. Copy/paste is separate from drag-and-drop, and I have never heard of remote drag-and-drop working.)

Comment: I must have been blind when I first looked at the link.

Comment: I wonder what the technical reason behind it not working is. Surely this is solvable... if only it was open source.